# Appcompat activity along with androidx gradle version issue in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, android-appcompat, androidx

[image: Android studio error]

Appcompat version used in app is v7, androidx is used for integration with `gradle.properties` for firebase connection
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong `build.gradle` file

You have to move the `implementation` from the **top-level** file to the `app/build.gradle` file in the `dependencies` block (not the dependencies in the `buildscript` block)::

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
   apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

   android {
    //...
   }

   dependencies {
        //...
        implementation 'androidx.xxxxx'
   }
```